# Why delete this post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just saw this show up in my reputation timeline:

> +2 7 hours ago removed [How is the average particle density defined in condensed matter physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165545/2451)

Can anyone tell me why this was removed? It does not show up as revently deleted post. Do i have any means of looking at it? I don't want to loose stuff i post here. I am not sure if this was a question i answered myself but if so i would really regret not being able to look at it if i need it.

So were can I see what that was and can anyone give a hint why it was deleted, for general couriosity?

And one point more. Do i need to be afraid posts like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165924/contructive-proof-of-2nd-quantization-form-of-operators)
 can be deleted? Where i answered myself so no votes and no accepted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. FYI, [OP's question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165545/2451) was deleted by the [Community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user following [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006) SE rules.
2. On the other hand, [this question of OP](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165924/2451) is not deleted by the same SE rules, since e.g. it has an answer.