# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I noticed that a question (see below) I asked a while back was deleted without a trace or any notification.

I don't have an issue with downvotes and closing. The question is admittedly fairly speculative. However, I don't see the purpose of outright deleting a question like this, since it doesn't contain any offensive content, and may in fact be of interest to some people.

Deleted question:

[Is mass/energy a measure of computational capacity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296580/2451)

Obviously computation requires energy, and there are known entropy bounds in relation to this. Here, I am asking if they are the same thing.

Sub-questions:

```
Is quantum mechanics a mechanism of computational minimization?

Is computational capacity preserved?

Is gravity a mechanism for clustering of computational capacity?

Is a black hole a computationally closed region, which attract computational capacity, but does not have computational power to transfer any subset of computational capacity outside the closed region?
```

Answer (score 1):

It was deleted by [Community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). For more information, see [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6787/2451) meta post.

Comment: Thanks. The deletion rules seem unnecessarily aggressive.

Comment: @HalfdanFaber Note that those rules are set by Stack Exchange, responding to the requirements of a [wide variety of different sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), and this community has no control over them. To learn more about why they're set like that, or to lobby for a change, the best place is [meta.se]. In particular, please note that all decisions are taken based on the content: it is a judgement of the post and not of you personally. Learn what you can about what questions are (and are not) a good fit for this site, and move on ;-).