# No comment to a deleted question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

As I noticed just know the question [Intrinsic spin and magnetic dipole moment of electrons bounded to the nucleus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287610/46708) was deleted. This seems to be a not so often carried out procedure.

Is there an automatically notification to the questioner?

Not sure why this question was deleted. Why there are no comments?

**And very specific to this case how [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287610/46708) question lowers the quality of PSE? Because only this could be the reason to delete something and not to show that it is a duplicate or to set it on hold because something is not well formulated.**

Comment: 1. Possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6787/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9465/2451 . 2. The no deletion comment/notification is by SE design. 3. New feature requests should go to the SE [mother meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why delete this post?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6787/t)

Comment: The claim that this is infrequent is not particularly correct - but your impression that it is infrequent is shaped by survivorship bias. This particular question was [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006) as RemoveDeadQuestions (i.e. 30 days after asking, with negative score and no answers). If you want questions to avoid this fate, keep them active, fix their problems, politely solicit advice if none is forthcoming, and listen to it when it does.

Comment: In this particular case, though, it's relatively easy to see why it was downvoted without explanation - it's yet another one in a long series of questions and answers pushing for your own personal non-mainstream theories, and it is frankly of very limited interest.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for your opinion. And I'm disappointed that not any of you scientists have shown any inconsistency of my own personal non-mainstream theories.

Comment: *not any of you scientists have shown any inconsistency of my **own personal non-mainstream theories*** This site isn't meant to review your own pet theories. We even have an active close reason that expressly **forbids** such questions, so why on earth would we bother answering such a question?

Comment: @KyleKanos Your question is easy to answer. As long as nobody shows any inconsistency in my elaborations I'm not satisfied. The linked question is a good example. I've related a lot of well known phenomena and made some conclusions. To say that a conclusion is not teached is strange to me. Show to me that the conclusion is impossible from the well known phenomena.

Comment: Note that you didn't actually answer my (rhetorical) question. And, satisfied or not with whatever responses you garner, your *personal* theories are **expressly off-topic** (as questions), so there is *zero reason* for anyone to answer it.